# Recurse through TreeView and create folders

Tags: vb.net, recursion, treeview

I want to build a function to recurse through a treeview and create each folder on a harddrive. The code is working fine so far. Once it reaches the end of a node it jumps one level deeper. But whta I am missing here is a line of code to jump back to the upper folder to continue creating the other folders.
This is what I have so far:

```
    Private Sub RecurseNodes(ByVal col As TreeNodeCollection)
    For Each tn As TreeNode In col
        Console.WriteLine(drive_letter & treefix & tn.Text)
        If tn.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
            treefix = treefix & tn.Text & "\"
            RecurseNodes(tn.Nodes)
        End If
    Next tn
End Sub
```

This is what my output looks like:

```html
E:\Auftraggeber Projektname 00000
E:\Auftraggeber Projektname 00000\Export
E:\Auftraggeber Projektname 00000\Material
E:\Auftraggeber Projektname 00000\Material\Original
E:\Auftraggeber Projektname 00000\Material\Transcodiert
E:\Auftraggeber Projektname 00000\Material\Footage
E:\Auftraggeber Projektname 00000\Material\GFX
E:\Auftraggeber Projektname 00000\Material\SFX
E:\Auftraggeber Projektname 00000\Material\Sprecher
E:\Auftraggeber Projektname 00000\Material\Projekt
E:\Auftraggeber Projektname 00000\Material\Musik
```

and this is what the tree actually looks like:
[image: TreeView]

So once the code gets to *E:\Auftraggeber Projektname 00000\Material\Footage*, it should go back the upper folder to continue processing.

It is probably just a single line or two of code but I just can't figure it out.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution in this case is to store the old value of the `treefix` variable before changing it, then revert to it after the inner `RecurseNodes()` call has exited:

```
If tn.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
    Dim currentPath As String = treefix
    treefix = treefix & tn.Text & "\"

    RecurseNodes(tn.Nodes)

    treefix = currentPath
End If
```

Though to avoid having to use class level variables, the more sustainable solution is to just pass the current path to your method. Also, do prefer [`Path.Combine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) when working with paths in general:

```
Private Sub RecurseNodes(ByVal col As TreeNodeCollection, ByVal currentDirectory As String)
    For Each tn As TreeNode In col
        Dim currentPath As String = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, tn.Text)
        Console.WriteLine(currentPath)

        If tn.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
            RecurseNodes(tn.Nodes, currentPath)
        End If
    Next tn
End Sub
```

Example usage:

```
RecurseNodes(TreeView1.Nodes, "E:\Auftraggeber Projektname 00000")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Passing the current path was a simple, but great idea. Thanks!

Comment: @max07 : Glad I could help! Happy coding!